# Python Scapy RTP header manipulation - how can I decode RTP in scapy?

Tags: python, scapy, rtp

I need to edit 2 RTP header fields in a PACP file.

I want to edit the `RTP timestamp` field and the `SSRC` field. This is so that I can manipulate some capture for replay using `tcpreplay` for testing end device for a couple of reasons.

Using the Python REPL i am able to load the file:

```
from scapy.all import rdpcap
pkts_list = rdpcap("foo.pcap")
```

the I get the length of the file

```
len(pkts_list)
```

then I can inspect a packet

```
pkts_list[xxx].show()
```

How / Can I decode / see RTP header information? Sorry scapy docs are a bit think for me on this one.

Thanks in advance

Neil

Comment: I think RTP(pkts_list[xxx]).timestamp might be a start ... but the result I get is the same for every packet where in wireshark they are incrementing ...

Comment: ok some progress 

`RTP(pkts_list[xxx]['UDP'].payload).timestamp` has got me there .... only issue now is struggling to set the list in index to a new value. `RTP(pkts_list[xxx]['UDP'].payload).timestamp = 0` doesn't do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RTP(pkts_list[xxx]['UDP'].payload).timestamp` did the job with a bit of trial and error

my other question is more python related I will ask that somewhere else.

Update:

Posting my full code for manipulating RTP headers as it took a lot of trial and error and very small titbits of info to sort it ... its a hack but it works, might help someone else.

```
### Python 2.7 Script by Neil Bernard neil@themoog.org
## This script is for editing RTP header information in PCAP files to manipulate RTP timestamp and SSRC
## for testing hardware transport stream devices and testing SMPTE 2022-2 handling

## There is some error checking for scapy network layers but try to keep capture as clean as possible
## also try to keep captures under 260Mb for performance, can take a good 20mins on an intel i7 / 16GB ram

#### Basic Scapy Tutorial

# *https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADDYo6CgeQY

#### Scapy cheat sheet

# https://blogs.sans.org/pen-testing/files/2016/04/ScapyCheatSheet_v0.2.pdf

#### Scapy RTP Library https://fossies.org/linux/scapy/scapy/layers/rtp.py

# import scapy
from scapy.all import rdpcap
from scapy.all import wrpcap
from scapy.all import RTP
from scapy.all import *

infile = "test_rtp.pcap"
outfile = "modified_" + infile
dest_port = 2000 # usefull to make sure you only action packets that are RTP

# load packet capture
print "Loading Packet Capture Keep <200Mb - Might take a few mins....."
pl = rdpcap(infile)
print "Loading complete!"

# print number of packets
print(len(pl))
# # print rtp timestamp
# print(RTP(pl[0][UDP].payload).timestamp)
numberofpckts = len(pl)

print numberofpckts

for pkt in range(numberofpckts):

    # You cant use the [RTP] layer on a list index so you have to put it in a
    # variable first. Also need to make sure its a UDP packet with .haslayer(UDP):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48763072/scapy-getting-trailer-field-in-the-dissector

    if pl[pkt].haslayer(UDP):
        packet = pl[pkt][UDP]

    else:
        print "Probably Not a UDP / RTP Packet# {0}".format(pkt)


    # You need to do the line below to force RTP detection and manipulation
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724186/decode-rtp-over-udp-with-scapy

    if pl[pkt].haslayer(UDP):
        if packet["UDP"].dport==2000: # Make sure its actually RTP
            packet["UDP"].payload = RTP(packet["Raw"].load)

        #### un-commment and change lines below to manipulate headers

            # packet[RTP].version = 0
            # packet[RTP].padding = 0
            # packet[RTP].extension = 0
            # packet[RTP].numsync = 0
            # packet[RTP].marker = 0
            # packet[RTP].payload_type = 0
            # packet[RTP].sequence = 0

            # packet[RTP].timestamp = 0

            packet[RTP].sourcesync = 0
            # packet[RTP].sync = 0

            ### Calculate UDP Checksum or they will now be wrong!

            #https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html

            checksum_scapy_original = packet[UDP].chksum

            # set up and calculate some stuff

            packet[UDP].chksum = None ## Need to set chksum to None before starting recalc
            packetchk = IP(raw(packet))  # Build packet (automatically done when sending)
            checksum_scapy = packet[UDP].chksum
            packet_raw = raw(packetchk)
            udp_raw = packet_raw[20:]
            # in4_chksum is used to automatically build a pseudo-header
            chksum = in4_chksum(socket.IPPROTO_UDP, packetchk[IP], udp_raw)  # For more infos, call "help(in4_chksum)"

            # Set the new checksum in the packet

            packet[UDP].chksum = checksum_scapy # <<<< Make sure you use the variable in checksum_scapy

            # needed below to test layers before printing newts/newsourcesync etc to console

            if pl[pkt].haslayer(UDP):
                newts = RTP(pl[pkt][UDP].payload).timestamp
                newsourcesync = RTP(pl[pkt][UDP].payload).sourcesync

            else:
                newts = 999
                newsourcesync = 999

            print("Changing packet {0} of {3} to new timestamp {1} SSRC {2} Old UDP chksum {4} >> New UDP chksum ???").format(pkt+1,newts,newsourcesync,numberofpckts,hex(checksum_scapy_original))

        else:
            print "Probably Not a UDP / RTP Packet# {0}".format(pkt)

# Write out new capture file
wrpcap(outfile, pl)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use from this command for write a rtp header packet. but whet you trying to write this packet in a pcap. you will see this error:

> TypeError: clone_with() got multiple values for keyword argument
>   'payload'

therefor you before write packet must change scapy/packet.py lib. this link explain better:

**https://github.com/CJTozer/scapy/commit/d0367f2efa86e65fa2b0a82a864b7fe89222f153**

Comment: This was fixed YEARS ago https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/scapy/layers/rtp.py